# Swashbuckle.Swagger - additionalProperties = false

Tags: c#, swashbuckle, openapi

I'm using
package id="Swashbuckle" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net471"

I'm accessing the schema at
http://SITE/swagger/docs/v1

The property 'additionalProperties' isn't printet.
I would like it to be set to: 'additionalProperties: false'.

using an ISchemaFilter I can only add a schema type to the field. Not set it to false. Is there any way to do this?

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Swashbuckle.Swagger
{
  public class Schema
  {
    public Dictionary<string, object> vendorExtensions = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    [JsonProperty("$ref")]
    public string @ref;
    public string format;
    public string title;
    public string description;
    public object @default;
    public int? multipleOf;
    public int? maximum;
    public bool? exclusiveMaximum;
    public int? minimum;
    public bool? exclusiveMinimum;
    public int? maxLength;
    public int? minLength;
    public string pattern;
    public int? maxItems;
    public int? minItems;
    public bool? uniqueItems;
    public int? maxProperties;
    public int? minProperties;
    public IList<string> required;
    public IList<object> @enum;
    public string type;
    public Schema items;
    public IList<Schema> allOf;
    public IDictionary<string, Schema> properties;
    public Schema additionalProperties;
    public string discriminator;
    public bool? readOnly;
    public Xml xml;
    public ExternalDocs externalDocs;
    public object example;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some of the code in your project?

Comment: It's just plane swagger setup. No customization at all.

Comment: The info you given is not enough to troubleshoot ...

Comment: I've installed the NuGet package - and thats it. So there isnt really more code I can show. I haven't changed the configuration or anything.

Comment: Where is the code for your ISchemaFilter ?

Comment: And by the way the additionalProperties is of type Schema not boolean, Why do you want to set it that to false?

Comment: My web dev say, it has something to do with TypeScript and the possibility to add your own fields on objects.